# Why doesn't Miss Martian turn into a white martian when the inhibitor collar is put on her?

Tags: dc, young-justice

In *Young Justice*, the inhibitor collar inhibits all superpowers. Considering Miss Martian is actually a white martian and using her powers to disguise herself as a green martian, shouldn't she turn into a white martian when the inhibitor collar is put on her?

Comment: It is speculated in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/youngjustice/comments/4c9jji/how_come_inhibitor_can_collars_block_natural/) that it might "lock" her abilities so can't change form with it on. Or it's because she's an "alien" so they aren't necessarily supernatural powers.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's no reason a transformation *shouldn't* remain until the user actively changes back.

Answer (score 2):

Without the reactions of other Martians to the same collar, we cannot be certain that she should revert to her natural form upon loss of her powers.

If she doesn't actively have to concentrate to maintain her form, then it would make sense that she'd maintain her form when asleep, knocked out, or having temporarily lost her powers.

(As an analogy: Back in the 1980s, Marvel's race of shape-shifters, the Skrulls, all lost the ability to change form. They were stuck in whatever form they were in when this happened. Many looked like other races; at least one had merged his body with some sort of weapons suit, and couldn't get out of it.)